# Sending secured request using a REST to appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, webservice-client, webservices-client

We have endpoints in our appengine app which is secured and needs Google login to invoke. There is no problem when we access it via browser (as it redirects to Google login). However it does not work when I use a REST client i.e.

```
GET url
```

Is there any way to configure REST clients like postman for oAuth so that it does not just return the HTML page of the login screen. I want to use the REST client because it has environment functionality where base URL can be switched easily.

Comment: You found an answer? Im trying to make postman hit my app engine it always returns {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Authorization required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Authorization required"
  }
}